# Unable to load Static files into my Index.html in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django and I am having a challenge in importing static files into my main HTML document. Can anybody help? Below is the approach I am following

My project structure looks like below. Hi2 is the project

[image]

settings.py looks like below. I did all the Important settings related to Static Files

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
'myapp'  
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFIELS_DIRS=[
STATIC_DIR,
]
```

My view file looks like below

```
from django.shortcuts import render

   # Create your views here.
   def index(request):
      return render(request,'myapp/index.html')
```

Finally imported CSS into my **index.html** in the below way. In the 3rd line Used  **{% load static %}** and in 14th and 17th lines used **"{% static "file location" %}"**. But it's not all reflecting when viewd Index.html page.

```
 1) <!DOCTYPE html>
 2)  <html lang="en">
 3)   {% load static %}
 4)   <head>
 5)  
 6)   <meta charset="utf-8">
 7)   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 8)   <meta name="description" content="">
 9)    <meta name="author" content="">
 10)  
 11)    <title>Home</title>
 12)  
 13)   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 14)   <link href="{% static 'myapp/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 15) 
 16)   <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 17)    <link href="{% static 'myapp/css/simple-sidebar.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 18) 
 19) </head>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks In Advance
Venk

Comment: show us, INSTALLED_APPS and your view

Comment: Hi, I just updated the details like INSTALLED_APPS and my view in the question. Can you please check?